# How to convert a pac script into Linux-style proxy environment variables?

Tags: windows, proxy, linux-networking, pac

On Windows machines (and networks with a lot of Windows machines), the use of Proxy Autoconfiguration scripts is rather ubiquitous for [reasons](https://serverfault.com/a/167578/113898); on Linux distributions (e.g. CentOS), [it is more common](https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/setting-a-proxy-in-centos-and-red-hat/) for applications to consult several environment variables: `http_proxy`, `https_proxy` and `no_proxy` for exceptions. Here's a sample setting of these three:

```
export http_proxy=http://my.proxy:8080
export https_proxy=https://my.proxy:8443
no_proxy=192.168.1.*,localhost,example.org
```

My question: Given a PAC script (say, as a text file or on the standard input stream), how can I obtain these three lines from it?

Now, I suspect the answer may be "you can't, they're Turing complete". If that's the case, are there classes of common PAC file templates which are simple enough to avoid a general hardness result?